# Is it possible to set different brightness for different attached screens through redshift / redshift-gtk in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

I have been using [redshift / redshift-gtk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift) to adjust the color temperature of my screen in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Dell XPS 15 (In Dell XPS, there is a common problem with brightness in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. So, redshift is also a good {not the best} tool to mitigate that problem.)

I'm also using an extended display. However, as the extended display is a little old, it's not easy to set its brightness manually using buttons. On the other hand, the settings I'm using for the main display through [redshift.conf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift) do not match properly with the extended display e.g. for a given brightness value in redshift.conf, the main display is too bright while the extended display is little dark/dull.

In redshift.conf, there are different parameters. So, I was wondering is it possible to set different parameters for different screens e.g. brightness value for the main display = 0.6 & brightness value for the extended display = 0.8?

Thanks in advance!